# How to set appearance or color scheme for different vscode instances?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using Visual Studio Code for my project. Sometimes I need to work on different git branches simultaneously, therefore I'll have multiple project copies in different folders with different branches, and open VS Code in each folder.

However, it bothers me that all VS Code instances look the same, therefore I can't distinguish which workspace I'm switching to immediately.

Is it possible to save IDE appearance or color scheme in VSCode workspace setting?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

The simplest solution might be using the [Peacock extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=johnpapa.vscode-peacock). It changes the color of your workspace (including titlebar, activitiy bar and status bar) using a single command:

`Peacock: Change to a favorite color`.

This is limited to a pre-defined color set, though.

[image: peacock extension]

Comment: great great great great

Answer (score 4):

You can have [workspace settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings). Open them by using the `Preferences: Open Workspace Settings (JSON)` command:

[image: open workspace settings command]

[Customize your theme](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color) there, e.g. change your status bar colour to red:

```json
{
    "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        "statusBar.background": "#9f2323",
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

With the extension [When File](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.WhenFile) you can color parts of the window based on the file path or languageId

A sample from the README

```
  "whenFile.change": {
    "byLanguageId": {
      "python": {
        "workbenchColor": {
          "editor.background": "#ddddff"
        }
      },
      "html": {
        "workbenchColor": {
          "editor.background": "#ddffdd"
        }
      }
    },
    "/projects/server/": {
      "workbenchColor": {
        "activityBar.background": "#509050"
      }
    },
    "/projects/client/": {
      "workbenchColor": {
        "activityBar.background": "#905080"
      }
    },
    "/.*\\.log$": {
      "workbenchColor": {
        "activityBar.background": "#acad60"
      }
    }
  }
```